# Yodlee REST API - addItemForContentService1

Tags: yodlee

Could you please provide a JSON sample of how you would post an addItemForContentService1 for a bank with a FieldInfoMultiFixed field. An example is Sallie Mae, content service ID #3805

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this in python. Replace some of the values such as cobrand_session_token, content_service_id with the actual values:
Most of the below is directly from [this documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addItemForContentService1).

---

```
payload = {"cobSessionToken": cobrand_session_token, "userSessionToken":  session["user_session_token"], "contentServiceId": content_service_id, "shareCredentialsWithinSite": True, "startRefreshItemOnAddition": True, "credentialFields.enclosedType": "com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoMultiFixed",\
    "credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier":"LOGIN",\
    "credentialFields[0].displayName":"UserID",\
    "credentialFields[0].isEditable":True,\
    "credentialFields[0].isEscaped":False,\
    "credentialFields[0].name":"LOGIN",\
    "credentialFields[0].helpText":5112,\
    "credentialFields[0].fieldType":"TEXT",\
    "credentialFields[0].valueMask":"LOGIN_FIELD",\
    "credentialFields[0].maxlength":40,\
    "credentialFields[0].size":20,\
    "credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier":"PASSWORD",\
    "credentialFields[1].displayName":"Password",\
    "credentialFields[1].isEditable":True,\
    "credentialFields[1].isEscaped":False,\
    "credentialFields[1].name":"PASSWORD",\
    "credentialFields[1].helpText":4530,\
    "credentialFields[1].fieldType":"IF_PASSWORD",\
    "credentialFields[1].valueMask":"LOGIN_FIELD",\
    "credentialFields[1].maxlength":40,\
    "credentialFields[1].size":20, "credentialFields[0].value":"content_account_username", "credentialFields[1].value":"content_account_password"}
```

Comment: As you were using SiteID instead of contentServiceId  because of which you were getting the exception and now your issue is resolved once you have used the correct contentServiceId value.

Comment: @Shreyans - isn't this person asking about addItemForContentService1 and not about addSiteAccount1? That's why I had contentServiceId in there, let me know if I'm missing something.